# Plink, backspace and bell

Tags: ssh, script, plink

I'm connecting to a remote SSH linux server from a windows host using plink.
This works correctly, I setup a private/public key and can authenticate without any problem.

Thing is, when using plink once I'm connected the backspace key produces odd characters (something like '<-[K') and I get bell rings from the computer every now and then.

This is really baffling because if I use PuTTY it works fine I can erase using backspace and no bell. What is even more odd is that plink is loading the session that I made using PuTTY.

This is the command I use : plink -load virtual_MMFU
Basically, the session works fine when used with PuTTY but whatever I change under keyboard or bell doesn't have any effect when using it with plink.

Comment: By chance you haven't happened to find a solution? I've run into the same problem and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try command 'stty erase ' first, then you'll find backspace key works as it supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "[MyEnTunnel](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel)". It's essentially a plink, but with some ease-of-use functions.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem earlier today, and I just resolved it.

Basically the problem, at least for me, is not in plink, but is because I call plink under powershell. Characters like <-[00, <-[K are in fact [ANSI escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and <-[K means erase in line. But both cmd and powershell does not support this.

I resolve this problem by installing Console2 and AnsiCon following [this link](http://blog.jimueller.com/post/29709142253/use-putty-with-console2).

It is surprising that this question is already two years old without a very good answer. So I just write this and hope it will help anyone who encounter this problem in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I also experienced this problem in windows 10 recently; this resolution worked for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315231

It boils down to starting plink with powershell:

powershell C:\path\plink.exe -load

Comment: that is why I am providing the gist that the user needs. It is not link only.